# How to store session in when click button start to again click button end time for calculate start to end time in php

Tags: php, html, cookies, session-variables

I want to chart for daily spending hours in browser. In the chart each day spending hours are mentioned. When I click the button time will start and again click the button time will end and finally calculate start to end time stored in like session or any other. This will happen for three days and finally chart will generate.

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="time_calculation.php" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="start" value="Start">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="end" value="End">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

php:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['start'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
    $time_start=date("Y-m-d h:i:s A"); 
    $_SESSION['start']='$time_start';
    echo "time start now ".$time_start."<br>";
}

if(isset($_POST['end'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
    $time_end=date("Y-m-d h:i:s A"); 
    $_SESSION['end']='$time_end';
    echo "time was ended".$time_end."<br>"; 
    $sst=strtotime($_SESSION['start']);
    $eet=strtotime($_SESSION['end']);
    $diff=$eet-$sst;
    $timeelapsed=mktime("h:i",$diff);
    echo $timeelapsed;
}
?>
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: when i click end  button it will show                                                     time was ended2016-11-23 10:58:43 AM

Warning: mktime() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\programs\time_calculation.php on line 23

Comment: So your issue is with the format of your `mktime()`. Or more speicifcally, you shouldn't be using `mktime()` there. You actually just want to use the `date()` method again.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the active session times on the database temporary table and calculate it for 3 days.

I am not clear with your requirements, if you need to track the details you can use available tools like [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)

Comment: in php how to calculate start to end time in session and display the difference time

Comment: I am trying to make a time track system using php in which i have two buttons like clock in and clock out . I am storing the clock in time and clock out time in session variables. Now my requirement is to calculate the difference between the clock in time and clock out time. If you have a clear idea about calculating the difference between the times share the thoughts with me

Answer (score 0):

`mktime()` is used to create a timestamp from an array of inputs. [PHP Man](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

I would suggest you change the code to take your date from the session and turn it back into a `DateTime` object. Then you can use [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) to get the difference in the `DateTime` and format the output to your liking.

```
$sst= new DateTime($_SESSION['start']);
$eet= new DateTime($_SESSION['end']);
$diff=date_diff($eet, $sst);
$timeelapsed=$diff->format('%r %a days %h hours and %i minutes');
echo $timeelapsed;
```

*edit:* Your php also has an issue with quoting your variables. Eg. You should not quote `$time_start` when trying to assign it's value to `$_SESSION['start']`. It is trying to assign the literal string, rather than the date object assigned to the variable.

**edit 2:** Here is the full code (changed to single page form/php)

```
<?php
session_start();

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="thisForm.php" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="start" value="Start">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="end" value="End">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['start'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
    $time_start = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A"); 
    $_SESSION['start'] = $time_start;
    echo "time start now $time_start <br>";
}

if(isset($_POST['end'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta'); 
    $time_end = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A"); 
    $_SESSION['end'] = $time_end;
    echo "time was ended $time_end <br>"; 
    $sst= new DateTime($_SESSION['start']);
    $eet= new DateTime($_SESSION['end']);
    $diff = date_diff($eet, $sst);
    $timeelapsed = $diff->format('%r %a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %S seconds');
    echo $timeelapsed;
}
?>
```

Comment: this will be show...0 day 0 hours 0 minutes .it does not calculate difference between start to end time

Comment: @j.mani this was tested and is in fact, exactly what it does.

Comment: I just noticed that comment could be read either way. My code was tested. And has been tested again. It works.

Comment: If you can't see it, add seconds to the format string `%S seconds`.