# php/mysql timer that use countdown from database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

please I need help with counter (timer) that use table data as minutes to count. For example, i table i have row that sets number 5 (it will always be in minutes) and on php page i have table with some rows. i need to create on every row Start/End button. Clinking on Start will user value from table and start counting 5:00, 4:59 etc. Problem is that timer should not reset after refresh page (many people will look at this page).

I have this script that calculates start time and end time, but it will reset after refresh.

I did not post while table with rows, I did not think it is necessary.
in table, output of column that contain minutes is

```
<?php echo $row['Trajanje_pauze'] ; ?>
```

this is my script, i found on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756643/how-to-store-session-in-when-click-button-start-to-again-click-button-end-time-f)

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
    <form action="msa_pauze.php" method="POST">
         <td> <input type="submit" name="start" value="Start"></td>
           <br><br>
         <td> <input type="submit" name="end" value="End"></td>
        </form> 
    <?php 

if(isset($_POST['start'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zagreb'); 
    $time_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
    $_SESSION['start'] = $time_start;
    echo "time start now $time_start <br>";
}

if(isset($_POST['end'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zagreb'); 
    $time_end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 
    $_SESSION['end'] = $time_end;
    echo "time was ended $time_end <br>"; 
    $sst= new DateTime($_SESSION['start']);
    $eet= new DateTime($_SESSION['end']);
    $diff = date_diff($eet, $sst);
    $timeelapsed = $diff->format('%r %a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %S seconds');
    echo $timeelapsed;
}
    ?>
```

Comment: can you add the script that does the countdown please ?

Comment: i posted a code (i write wrong, it is not script it is php code). This have start and end button and calculate differeance

Comment: better to have a field with the future time, when the timer is finished (when creating it, put "now + 600 seconds" in). Then just subtract "now" from the future time and you'll have the remaining seconds...

Comment: Ok, it is not problem to add future time in table. Also i found this [https://www.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm] countdown script

Comment: i know this is `php` code and i asked for the `javascript` script to see if we can add a function that sends `ajax` requests when the countdown is updated ( every second or so ) to update the database so all the other users can see the exact time left, and if you need the only current user to see that, you'll have to keep it in a cookie or localStorage or something,

Comment: ok, I found this script :
`<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
 
   var refreshId_sec = setInterval(function() {   
      var target_url = 'php/show_diff.php?show=all&randval='+ Math.random();      
   jQuery.ajax({url: target_url, success: function(result){
  
  var arr_res = result.split("|");  
  
  document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML = arr_res[3];
  document.getElementById('min').innerHTML = arr_res[2];
  document.getElementById('hour').innerHTML = arr_res[1];
  document.getElementById('day').innerHTML = arr_res[0];
  
    }});

   }, 1000);
</script>`

Comment: here is target url php:
`<?php
$then = '2018-4-4 10:00:00'; // end time here
$then = new DateTime($then, new DateTimeZone('Croatia/Zagreb'));

$now = new DateTime();
 
$sinceThen = $then->diff($now);
 
if($_GET["show"]=="all")
 echo $sinceThen->d."|".$sinceThen->h."|".$sinceThen->i."|".$sinceThen->s;
else
{ 
 if($_GET["show"]=="day")
  echo $sinceThen->d;
 else if($_GET["show"]=="hour")
  echo $sinceThen->h;
 else if($_GET["show"]=="min")
  echo $sinceThen->i;
 else if($_GET["show"]=="sec")
  echo $sinceThen->s;
} 
?>`

Comment: Hey i found this little code that i think will work for me:

'<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Zagreb');  

$dt_end = new DateTime($row['Start_pauze']);
//$dt_end = new DateTime('2018-03-23 10:00:00');
$remain = $dt_end->diff(new DateTime());
echo $remain->i . ' minutes' . $remain->s . ' seconds ';
?>'